# In which cases is the summation function distributive?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

When working on the proof for 
$$\det(\text{A} -\lambda \text{I})=\det(\text{Q}^{-1}\text{ B Q}-\lambda \text{I})$$
where $\lambda$ is a scalar, $\det$ is the determinant, $\text{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\text{A}$ is similar to $\text{B}$. I made the following calculation:
$$\det(\text{A} -\lambda \text{I})= \sum^n_{j=1}(a_{kj} - \lambda e_{kj}) \ \text{C}_{kj}$$
where $a_{ij},e_{ij}$ are entries in matricies $\text{A}$ and $\text{I}$ respectively, and $\text{C}_{ij}$ is the co-factor of $(a_{ij} - \lambda e_{ij})$. Now, I cannot distribute the summation function because $\text{C}_{ij}$ relates the the matrix $\text{A} - \lambda \text{I}$ and not the two matricies taken separately.
$$\det(\text{A} -\lambda \text{I}) \neq \sum^n_{j=1}a_{kj} \ \text{C}_{kj} - \lambda \sum^n_{j=1}e_{kj} \text{C}_{kj}$$

The proof should be calculated using left and right distributive laws of matrix multiplication, noting that
$$\det(\text{Q}^{-1}\text{ B Q}-\lambda \text{I})=\det(\text{Q}^{-1}\text{BQ}-\lambda \text{I Q}^{-1} \text{Q})$$

Comment: I am not if this is related to your question and you may know this already, but there is a much easier proof that:  $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(Q^{-1} B Q - \lambda I)$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in the last line.

Comment: So you have a proof?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to figure out what was wrong with the first method I used, but I only figured that out once I had typed the question. I decided to leave the question typed up, just to add to the collection on MSE.

Comment: I was hoping that somebody could direct me to general cases when I can distribute the summation function and when not.

Comment: I'm not sure that I really can't separate $(a_{kj} - \lambda e_{kj})$, because $k$ would be the same value in both $\sum^n_{j=1}a_{kj} \ \text{C}_{kj}$ and $\sum^n_{j=1}e_{kj} \text{C}_{kj}$. What do you think?
In any case, I don't think this question is good enough, so I am considering deleting it.